# Javascript window.onload not firing

Tags: javascript, onload

I am trying to write a javascript function that forces an element to have the style display = block.
Currently it is being set to display = none by another piece of javascript.

I thought `window.onload` would solve the problem as the code is then not being overridden  by the previous JS. The below code used to work and now the function just doesn't even fire.

Can anyone Help?

```
          window.onload =  function ()   // It sets the class of the unordered list when the page has been loaded.
            {
               ul.style.display = "block!important";   // Display all the child items
             }
```

Comment: Why not doing this with some CSS?

Comment: A Note: You should not use `element.onevent = callback;`  but `element.addEventListener(event, callback)`. The problem with the `element.onevent = callback;` it that it might be overwritten by another code. Especially `window.onload = callback` is a really bad idea.

Comment: I couldn't do it with css as it was being overwritten by some other JS. That's why I wanted to apply my JS after everything had loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get your `ul` in the callback of the event listener because if you do it before, the DOM is not fully loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var ul = document.getElementById("my-ul");

    ul.style.display = "block!important";
});
```

You can do it with JQuery if you want a more cross browser solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-ul').css('display', 'block!important');
});
```

You can do it in css:

```
#my-ul {
    display: block!important;
}
```

Your `ul` should be of the form for these solutions to work:

```
<ul id="my-ul">
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first solution worded perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `ul.style.display` like that.

Use `document. getElementsByTagName('ul').style.display = "block !important"`

Comment: Thanks for this. However the ul is already defined further up in the code. I only placed a small snippet in here. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score -1):

window.onload = function() ...    is defining a function. Just call the function right after you close it with window.onload();   Worked for me after many hours